# Python API design pattern question

Tags: python

I often find I have class instances that are descendants of other class instances, in a tree like fashion. For example say I'm making a CMS platform in Python. I might have a Realm, and under that a Blog, and under that a Post. Each constructor takes it's parent as the first parameter so it knows what it belongs to. It might look like this:

```
class Realm(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password)

class Blog(object):
    def __init__(self, realm, name)

class Post(object);
    def __init__(self, blog, title, body)
```

I typically add a create method to the parent class, so the linkage is a bit more automatic. My Realm class might look like this:

```
class Realm(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        ...
    def createBlog(self, name):
        return Blog(self, name)
```

That allows the user of the API to not import every single module, just the top level one. It might be like:

```
realm = Realm("admin", "FDS$#%")
blog = realm.createBlog("Kittens!")
post = blog.createPost("Cute kitten", "Some HTML blah blah")
```

The problem is those create methods are redundant and I have to pydoc the same parameters in two places.

I wonder if there's a pattern (perhaps using metaclasses) for linking one class instance to a parent class instance. Some way I could call code like this and have the blog know what it's parent realm is:

```
realm = Realm("admin", "FDS$#%")
blog = realm.Blog("Kittens!")
```

Comment: You mean the *instances* are descendants of one another. For a moment, I thought you were reinventing OOP.

Comment: You're right, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a common base class for the containers featuring an `add()` method

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.children = []
        self.parent = parent
    def add(self, child)
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)
        return child
```

and make the `parent` parameter optional in the derived classes

```
class Blog(Container):
    def __init__(self, name, realm=None):
        Container.__init__(realm)
        self.name = name
```

Your code above would now read

```
realm = Realm("admin", "FDS$#%")
blog = realm.add(Blog("Kittens!"))
post = blog.add(Post("Cute kitten", "Some HTML blah blah"))
```

You wouldn't have any `create...()` methods any more, so no need to document anything twice.

If setting the parent involves more than just modifying the `parent` attribute, you could use a property or a setter method.

**EDIT**: As you pointed out in the comments below, the children should be tied to the parents by the end of the contstructor.  The above approach can be modified to support this:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
    def add(self, cls, *args)
        child = cls(self, *args)
        self.children.append(child)
        return child

class Realm(Container):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        ...

class Blog(Container):
    def __init__(self, realm, name):
        ...

class Post(Container):
    def __init__(self, blog, title, body):
        ...

realm = Realm("admin", "FDS$#%")
blog = realm.add(Blog, "Kittens!")
post = blog.add(Post, "Cute kitten", "Some HTML blah blah")
```

Comment: That works, but I was thinking of some way to tie them together by the end of the constructor running. So that Blog can't exist even temporarily without having a parent (maybe it raises an exception like "this cannot be constructed directly, construct it from the context of a parent" or something).

Comment: Your add method needs to return the child here.  Currently add doesn't return anything so the line blog = realm.add(..) will result in blog == None

Comment: @darkporter: Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm, I like that. It gives you bi-directional linkage so you can iterate your children. Let me play around. And answer accepted.

Comment: In that case I'd remove the parent from the constructor args. There'd just be a general purpose "parent" property I'd check.

Comment: Nevermind actually, that won't work. But keeping it how you have it, as long as by convention the first arg is the parent, that works.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, just subclassing it. In my Realm constructor:

```
class Realm(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        ...
        parent = self
        original_constructor = blog.Blog.__init__
        class ScopedBlog(blog.Blog):
            def __init__(self, *args):
                self.parent = parent
                original_constructor(self, *args)
        self.Blog = ScopedBlog
```

Seems to work. And it could be generalized with base classes or meta classes.